# Redis command line syntax

Tags: redis

Can someone please explain how the following Redis command gives me back the content? What do the individual numbered lines are responsible for?

```
1: *3
2: $4
3: hget
4: $21
5: zc:k:b23_cache_config
6: $1
7: d
8: $5264$5264
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message format is called the [unified request protocol](http://redis.io/topics/protocol).

An asterisk `*` denotes how many arguments are to be expected in this request. So, `*3` is for  three arguments.

A dollar sign `$` denotes how many bytes are to be expected in the argument. So, `$1` is for one byte.

```
*<number of arguments> CR LF
$<number of bytes of argument 1> CR LF
<argument data> CR LF
...
$<number of bytes of argument N> CR LF
<argument data> CR LF
```

The raw message from your example would look like:

```
*3\r\n$4\r\nhget\r\n$21\r\nzc:k:b23_cache_config\r\n$1\r\nd\r\n
```

[This particular request](http://redis.io/commands/hget) will return a `bulk reply response`, which looks like:

```
$<number of bytes> CR LF
<DATA> CR LF
```

If the requested key doesn't exist then the reply will be:

```
$-1
```

Comment: What does the 'd' argument stand for in the hget command? Looked up the docs but could not find any reference.

Comment: `zc:k:b23_cache_config` is a [hash](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#hashes), and in that hash there is a `d` field. The `hget` command is requesting the value associated with the `d` field in the hash `zc:k:b23_cache_config`.